# Changing Nhibernate Connectionstring

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-xml

simple question how do i change the connection string of the nhibernate at runtime ?

```
 <property name="connection.connection_string"  >value</property>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tinkering with your app.config on the fly is a bit horrible.

I'd suggest not storing your connection string amongst the other nhibernate settings. Keep your various connection strings elsewhere (e.g. in appSettings), then set the appropriate connection string directly against your NH Configuration:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", "...connection string...");
configuration.Configure();
```

Just make sure that the connection.connection_string setting is not specified in your config file, as configuration.SetProperty will only work correctly if the setting is not there already.

Answer (score 2):

nevermind i got it.

```
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var root = XElement.Load(configuration.FilePath);
        root.Elements().Where(m => m.Name.LocalName == "hibernate-configuration").First().Elements().First().Elements().Where(m => m.FirstAttribute.Value == "connection.connection_string").First().Value = cs;
        root.Save(configuration.FilePath);
```

Comment: It's generally advised not to monkey with your app.config once your app is deployed, it'd suggest storing the connection string config in local app settings.  What if the user doesn't have permission to change the file in the program files directory?

Comment: As jonnii said, this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to switch connections based on some conditions (such as having one website with live and demo mode, each with different connection string) then it´s probably best to implement a class inherited from DriverConnectionProvider and set this class as value of the connection.provider configuration property in your config file.
See http://jasondentler.com/blog/2009/11/authentication-impersonation-and-dynamic-nhibernate-connection-strings/

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go with `Enterprise Library` and its `Data Access Application Block` to provide the NHibernate sessions APIs with proper named connectiong strings when instantiating a session API.

The DAAB has the feature to instantiate a `DbConnection` based on the configuration file. So you could possibly use several connection strings definition, and tell DAAB what connection to use, then pass it to your NHibernate session so that you may work with NHibernate against multiple datastores at once.

Using this approach will avoid you messing with the configuration file on runtime, and even allows you to create your own connections instance without having them defined in the configuration file at once.